# O que significa esse comando no git "^"?

Tags: git, linha-de-comando

Não gosto de ficar usando comandos sem sabe o significado, então, alguém saberia me dizer o que significa esse comando no git: **`^`** ?

Comment: Um exemplo para ajudar, achei esse comando para recuperar arquivo, mas não sei o que o "^" significa: git checkout <hash_commit>^ -- <caminho_arquivo>

Comment: É uma espécie de "negação"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine que você queria ver a diferença do seu diretório atual com o commit "pai", você utiliza o `^`

por exemplo:

```
git show <branch>^
```

Exibe as diferenças entre sua cópia e o commit pai

e se você quiser ver a diferença entre o "avô", você pode

```
git show <branch>^^
```

e assim vai somando `^` para voltar na árvore

para um referência oficial, visite este [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial#_exploring_history)